# Rounding issue in formula used in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Please could someone help. I have used this formula in my Tableau Desktop so that in the tooltip (when I hover on the bar chart) it can display figures with 0 Decimal Places.

```
int(IIF((ZN(round(SUM([Rental Area])),0) - LOOKUP(ZN(round(SUM([Rental Area])),0), -1)) / ABS(LOOKUP(ZN(round(SUM([Rental Area])),0), -1))
=-1,null,ZN(round(SUM(Rental Area])),0) - LOOKUP(ZN(round(SUM([Rental Area])),0), -1)))
```

What it is displaying is...example 349.0 or 45.0 and NOT 349 or 45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click your calculated field in the Measures pane and choose "Default Properties -> Number Format". In the Number Format window that opens, choose "Number (Custom)" and set to zero decimal places.

Comment: Thank you. Converted to a calculation and also Right clicked, change Data Type - Number (whole)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your IIF statement inside INT. Hope that will help. Refer to [Tableau community link.](https://community.tableau.com/thread/157952)

Comment: Sorry I tried changing the Round to INT and removing ,0) but showing as error.

Comment: You can put INT just outside IIF instead of replacing round and see if that works.